# civiCRM Cron only run one mail_report scheduled jobs?

Tags: civireport, cron-job

I'm using CiviCRM 4.4.6 in drupal 7.

In my scheduled jobs list, I had 3 scheduled jobs of membership report: report A, report B, and report C. These reports will send out email with different csv attachment.

When I click "Execute now", these 3 reports send email perfectly.

I'm using Elysia Cron to control both drupal and CiviCRM cron, and use external crontab to run cron in my control panel.

CiviCRM cron runs, but it only trigger report A. Both report B and C is missing.

My question is:

Does CiviCRM cron only allow one mail_report scheduled job to be run?

If so, does it mean that I have to put in multiple report IDs (instanceId) in one mail_report scheduled job?

I tested it, and only one instanceId is allowed in one mail_report scheduled job.

Is there any way I can send out multiple email reports when running cron?

Comment: When you add a job calling the same API using the Scheduled Job manager, it overwrites the old job. This is for CiviCRM 4.5.1 running on D7. Is there another method to do this?

Answer (score 8):

You have to create 3 instances of the mail_report scheduled job.

To do that, use `Add New Scheduled Job` button on the `Settings - Scheduled Jobs` page (`civicrm/admin/job?reset=1`)

On the creation page, set API call to `Job` / `mail_report` (`api.job.mail_report`) and define in `Command parameters` the appropriate `instanceId` and `format` options.

[image]

Comment: Fairly sure the OP did that: he says `In my scheduled jobs list, I had 3 scheduled jobs of membership report: ...When I click "Execute now", these 3 reports send email perfectly.`