# Fatal Error on manually executing Report Sender (daily)

Tags: cron-job

If I execute the Job manually I get the following error in the log and no email

> Parameters raw (from db settings): 
>   instanceId=[573]
>
> Parameters parsed (and passed to API method): 
>   a:2:{s:7:"version";i:3;s:10:"instanceId";s:5:"[573]";}
>
> Full message: 
>   Finished execution of Report sender with result: Failure, Error message: A > fatal error was triggered:  is not of type String

I've tried it with or without the optional format option, but I'm not convinced I'm entering the parameters correctly because although I can see the instructions I haven't actually seen a working version that I can examine the parameters on. Hopefully someone will point me in the right direction or tell me what else I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 2):

It's Ok I was not removing the square brackets in the example, I found a working example here - [civiCRM Cron only run one mail_report scheduled jobs?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/3918/civicrm-cron-only-run-one-mail-report-scheduled-jobs)

All working now :)